$\text{dim }Y=\text{dim }\overline{Y}$ for $Y$ being a quasi-projective variety.
This is exercise 2.7b) in Hartshorne and I wonder if anyone can verify whether my proof is correct. I I only assume that this fact is known to be true for quasi-affine variets (that is Proposition 1.10 in Hartshorne), and that for every family of open subsets $\{U_i\}$ that cover a topological space $X$, $\text{dim }X=\sup \text{dim } U_i$ (that is exercise 1.10b))
Let $Y_i=Y\cap U_i$ where $U_i$ is the complement of the hyperplane given by the polynomial $x_i$. Further, we know that $\overline{Y_i}\supseteq \overline{Y}\cap U_i$, since $U_i$ is open. $Y_i$ is homogeneous to quasi-affine varieties, thus we know by Prop 1.10, that $\text{dim }Y_i=\text{dim }\overline{Y_i}$ for every $i$. By exercise 1.10b) we know that $$\text{dim }Y= \sup \text{dim }Y_i$$ and $$\text{dim }\overline{Y}=\sup \text{dim }\overline{Y}\cap U_i\leq \sup\text{dim }\overline{Y_i},$$
since $\overline{Y_i}\supseteq \overline{Y}\cap U_i$. But since $\overline{Y_i}\subseteq \overline{Y}$, we also have $\text{dim }\overline{Y}\geq \sup\text{dim }\overline{Y_i}$. Therefore, we have equality. Consequently, it follows that
$$\text{dim }Y= \sup \text{dim }Y_i =\sup \text{dim }\overline{Y_i}  = \text{dim }\overline{Y} $$
what proves the claim.
I'd really appreciate any feedback on this proof. In particular, I am unsure because in $\overline{Y_i}\supseteq \overline{Y}\cap U_i$ at the beginning, I implicitly consider the closure of $Y_i$ as quasi-projective variety, but at $\text{dim }Y_i=\text{dim }\overline{Y_i}$ I implicitly consider the closure of $Y_i$ as quasi-affine variety, and I am not sure how this goes along, or if they are just equal? (if so, why?)
I assume that one might use exercise 2.6 for this, but I am not sure how precisely I should do this

If Y is a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$, show that $\text{dim }S(Y)=\text{dim }Y+1$


Your proof looks good to me.
Do you know what the affine cone of a projective variety is? If not, it is the union in affine n+1 space of the lines corresponding to points of a projective variety embedded in P^n. The coordinate ring of the affine cone of Y is S(Y). First observe that the affine cone of the closure of Y is the closure of the affine cone. Proposition 1.10 then allows you to say that the affine cones of Y and $\overline{Y}$ have the same dimension. Then Exercise 2.6 tells you that a projective variety has dimension one less than its affine cone, so we conclude $Y$ and $\overline{Y}$ have the same dimension.
